# SettingsPropertyValue.UsingDefaultValue Not Working?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

For the life of me, I cannot get this property to evaluate to *true*. It is always *false*, for any type of setting value I test: string, boolean, application or user setting, you name it.

Am I missing something obvious?

Here's my - very basic - code, residing in a class library and tested from a consuming Form app:

```
If My.Settings.PropertyValues.Item("StringSetting").UsingDefaultValue Then My.Settings.StringSetting = My.Settings.StringSetting ' Force saving to config file
```

(I've also tested using a very basic Form on it's own. No joy.)

`IsDirty` works fine and as expected, but `UsingDefaultValue` just evaluates to *false* no matter what.

BTW, what I'm trying to do is force the writing of a `StringCollection` type setting to the *user.config* file on first application start so it can be manually changed - rather than created - if necessary. I can't easily compare the current value to the `DefaultValue` property because this is saved as serialized XML instead of a collection/array. Yes, I know there're other ways and means to do this, but my question is why the `UsingDefaultValue` property doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `UsingDefaultValue` lets you know that when the Property is deserialized (it's always deserialized when you create the `SettingsPropertyValue` collection or you read the Setting's value), the value was null or could not be deserialzed, so the value of the `DefaultValue` Property is used instead, if possible. If you want to know whether the *default value* is currently used, compare `My.Settings.PropertyValues("SettingName").SerializedValue` and `My.Settings.Properties("SettingName").DefaultValue` (both are always strings).

Comment: Thanks @Jimi, I'll try that. But that `UsingDefaultValue` behavior is a bit misleading, no? And I have seen the same behavior for simple types such as `Boolean` and `String`. (Also, for complex setting types, apparently `IsDirty` is "pessimistically" set if its properties are accessed, according to documentation.)

Comment: Yes, the docs about `UsingDefaultValue` can be misleading, until you know [what they're talking about](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/configuration/SettingsPropertyValue.cs,138). The description about `IsDirty` is more complete and it's actually just what it is, in relation to *complex* types, so it cannot be used to determine whether the *default value* (the original value) of a Setting is currently used. -- Since `DefaultValue` is always a string, you can compare it with the currently serialized value (or `PropertyValue.ToString()`, it should be the same).

Comment: @Jimi Personally I think that the coded interpretation of `UsingDefaultValue` is a bit lame; why didn't they do the comparison you've suggested between `DefaultValue` and `SerializedValue`, which is actually the result we're looking for and a much more intuitive result?

Comment: Probably you have misinterpreted (you're not alone :) the meaning of `UsingDefaultValue`; the `Using` term may be more clear if you read as: *to return the Setting Value, we're Using the DefaultValue since the current Value is null or could not be deserialized*.